What would a planet need to have a sustained blood-based water cycle?
To keep it short, I have a planet with oceans of pure blood. It also 'rains' blood. Because of the planet, a blood-based water cycle consequently forms.
I'm aware that blood is far too viscous for this but I'm not satisfied with just using the real life phenomenon of blood rain. I want real blood.
My question is: What would my planet need to achieve this?

nothing science based, evaporation is a purifying process, so your rain at least will alwyas start as water.

The answer to your question is that it is not possible to have pure blood rain unless you want to use magic, in which case anything is possible.

When you say blood, are you attached to the physical properties of what to us in real life is blood; or are in attached to the idea of it raining whatever liquid that your organisms have running through their veins in order to transport bodily resources?

@Flater The former

The first thing blood does when it comes into contact with air is clot, you don't have blood rain you have scab hail.

Slightly related.

Raining real blood is a non-starter
Don't get me wrong, this sounds like an awesome setting, but it cannot exist in a science-based way. Rain is a consequence of evaporation which is a phase state that happens when the molecules in water become so excited that they lose their bonds to one another. However, blood is a suspension of water and solid particles (mainly blood cells). When you evaporate a suspension, the pure water escapes and the solids particles are left behind. So your planet would still rain water, even if the oceans, rivers, and lakes were all filled with blood.
Even if you were to get the substances that make up the blood cells to evaporate, they would no longer be blood cells. Cells are complex molecular compositions. When you vaporize them, they lose the solid state configuration that gives them their properties and destroy the information-bearing nucleic acids that contains the knowledge of how those atoms need to be put together to make the cell to begin with.
And this is all before you consider the fact that blood can only exist in symbiosis with a complex organism. It needs a respiratory system for gas exchange, a digestive system for nutrient exchange and energy, marrow for reproduction. So, blood is not like bacteria, it can't live unto itself.
But what if your rain is actually just a spray?
While a suspension cannot be evaporated, it can be sprayed into the air and will come down like rain. Yes, your planet will experience evaporation, and regular rain too, but it is also possible that your whole planet, or large parts of it, are covered by giant organisms. One of the hard parts about designing megafauna is creating enough surface area for respiration and cooling; so, perhaps your organisms have adapted by spraying their blood into the air in giant geysers so it can oxidize and cool down, and then taking it back up when it pools back down on them.
So, while this would not technically be rain, you could have a plant covered in rivers and pools of blood where blood perpetually falls from the sky thanks to a network of blood geysers.
Caveats to Consider
The higher the blood spray, the more energy your megafauna is expending on this process. To get a truly rain-like spray, you will need to spray the blood very high, but a more realistic approach may be to keep your geysers height-limited. So, you'll need to weigh how much you value the rule-of-cool here vs realism. Personally I suggest leaning into the rule-of-cool and going with volcano-sized blood geysers. This will make weather easier to explain since a whole village could be in the blood spray one day, but then a shift in wind, or the megafauna slightly shifting its position, could lead to clear skys even though the megafauna would obviously need to keep spraying blood 24/7 to stay alive.
The deeper the pools of blood that form, longer the blood will have to sit before it can be reabsorbed for oxygen uptake and the fewer cycles you will get out of a generation of blood. That means that your blood should not have the depth of an open ocean, but it can form massively wide and shallow lagoons just deep enough to sail. There are parts of the ocean that span over 100km but never get deeper than 1-3 meters; so, you may want to consider this the norm for your blood oceans, as opposed to Earth's oceans that can get many km deep. That said, you can't tell how deep blood is past a few mm because it is mostly opaque; so a lack of depth would not be apparent in your setting unless you choose to address it.
Blood carries an organism's immune system. Any living creature on this planet that is parasitic to the megafauna risks becoming a target of this immune system. This will probably lead to much less biodiversity than you see on Earth, and nearly all life that exists here will have to serve a symbiotic relationship to the megafauna or risk being the target of a global autoimmune response.

Awesome answer that both outlines the fundamental problems with the question AND offers a solution that works science based. Also I really love the concept of gigantic life forms (or a single life form that make up the planet) breathing by spraying the blood in the air and reabsorbing it from the oceans and seas. Drilling a well would basically be the try to find a bloodvessel.

Agree spray is a good solution, although the energy requirement of replacing passive evaporation with spraying liquid into the atmosphere will be massive. A single tree can transpire over 100L of water in a day, and if we assume that water vapor rises just 1km through the atmosphere, we're talking about a Megajoule of energy to replace the evaporative capacity of just one tree! Replacing the huge amount of free solar energy that drives the water cycle with a biological process will be a challenge - the megafauna might need another source of energy like geothermal.

@NuclearHoagie Agreed.  Megafauna tend to come with thier own set of Worldbuilding issues, and while I would not call this a Hard-Science solution, I think it passes the Science-Based threshold.

Another important point to consider: Blood is a living, breathing bodily tissue (that happens to be a liquid). For human blood, the Red Cross says it is no longer suitable for transfusion after 42 days, if stored in ideal conditions (i.e. with appropriate temperature control). Even in the body, red blood cells are typically broken down and replaced after ~120 days. if you have an ocean of blood on the surface of the planet, most of it is probably going to be dead within a fairly short period of time, unless it forms a symbiotic relationship with something else to sustain and replenish it.

Flying machines seeding clouds with blood cells?

You're going to run into a huge energy problem here--if the objective is to obtain oxygen you're limited by the energy it yields.  Extrapolating from what the heart uses and a severed artery can do I doubt you'll obtain energy even throwing it 100m up.

Maybe the Planet has some strong updrafts, which help to carry the sprayed blood higher? If there is some Volcanic activity, maybe regular strong updrafts are strong enough to carry the blood high into the atmosphere? This would limit the expended energy.

These blood spouts can have cooling as secondary function, as the blood is going to lose a lot of warmth being scattered through the air. This is is a good thing, as it can (partially) counteract the normal problem you get with big creatures overheating.

@vinzzz001 Great point.  I've added that to my answer.

Airborne creatures
As other answers have pointed out, evaporating blood is basically a non-starter, as the solid components of blood will be left behind. We can't really replace the evaporative component of the water cycle, but how else can we get the blood up in the sky to fall back down again? Something must carry it up.
Maybe this world has large flocks of airborne creatures which periodically replace or excrete some of their blood for some reason. The creatures could actively fly or passively float, allowing large flocks to stay airborne for a long time. The might need to come to the ground to feed, but they could use passive air currents to lift themselves and their payload into the air. One of these bloodstorms would be a bit like getting pooped on by a flock of seagulls. It'd probably be a tough sell to have planet-wide weather systems based on this approach (or to fill entire oceans with their blood), but a bloody squall accompanying a flying flock of unusual alien creatures might be plausible.

Sooo... synchronized bat mensuration?

Rather synchronized cloud menstruation

You need a magic tag for this.
If the tags had magic instead of/added to science based, it would have been kinda plausible.
I imagine a vampire coven(or whatever) having enough of their food/blood drying out after leaving it for a while, and they decide the best thing to do is to create an curse/enchantment that prevents blood from ever drying. Something went wrong, and it ended up as a worldwide one.
It works by preventing the blood elements from separating. If you heat it too much it now evaporates since it can't dry out, magic tying the blood-components together. It also kind of averages out the evaporation temperature.
With more and more blood being added the environment, you end up with blood seas and rain eventually.

What Is the Sky? What Is the World?
Ages ago, there were Builders, or so the stories say.  There was a sun, a ball of light.  Was it impossibly far away?  So they say.
The Builders had a sky that was nothing, empty, lights above it and ground beneath.  But in our day the sky bleeds.
It wasn't meant to bleed; the sky always gave us light, in the vast fleshy chambers that are our world.  They say that the sky has eyes, still looking up at the sun, drinking light, desperate to do its duty and give its light to us.
The sky was once bright, exhaling sweet air and shedding a friendly, loving glow in the day, a gentle whisper of light at night.
But now, weight of ages on weight of ages, the sky bleeds - the light grows garish and the nights black.  The air is heavy with the stink of decay - of decaying blood and a dying sky.  The rivers of blood, the sky's blood, pooling rotting in the dimnes...  Does the ailing sky hungrily drink back its own blood?  Who knows.
Someday, the prophets say, the sky will grow weary, it will fall on us all, and choke us and crush us.  In the miserable dimness, perhaps that would the final mercy, the last boon the loving sky could grant us.

Good worldbuilding, but totally eschews the "science-based" tag.

@NuclearHoagie Not at all - an engineered organism which cares for its occupants, but is now dying, hemorrhaging, is the only plausible, science-based answer answer I've seen to justify a literal cycle of blood raining down, flowing, pooling, etc.

No.  The blood would die.
Blood is an immensely complex, dynamic, and living system consisting of many different parts.  Even in an animal, blood is continually breaking down and being replenished.  Outside a living organism, the cells in it would continually die and not be replaced.
Furthermore, many parts of it are solid.  Evaporation would certainly leave them behind.

Water(blood)spouts!
If the weather on your planet had the perfect conditions to generate powerful tornadoes/hurricanes/waterspouts, then they could be constantly sucking up blood and dispersing it in downbursts of bloody rain.

How strict are you on what constitutes "blood"?
Your planet has a major ecosystem high in the atmosphere--very small floaters.  Put enough helium in the atmosphere that they can concentrate it out for lift.
The floaters aren't able to stand up to rain, though.  When a thunderhead reaches high enough it washes a bunch of them out.  What comes down tends to have the consistency of blood.

Since several answers conclusively explained only the water portion of the blood would evaporate, and you want it to “rain” blood, then what you need are storms frequent and violent enough to have tornados, cells, and spouts that draw the blood from the surface upwards into the lower atmosphere. It would be a violent and messy place. A large and dense atmosphere with a strong sun would help. Throw in a binary star system with frequent sun spots and solar flares, and it could be possible.

Space Blood!
So for reasons already discussed an earth-like planet is hostile to blood just being everywhere. If you allow for a wider variety of environments and don't require unprotected humans to live there I believe this could be possible in a modified atmosphere. You'd want these properties:
Low-gravity
Since we're ruling out evaporation you need a way for the blood to get into the air through kinetic energy (sprayed, launched, dropped). A low-gravity planet makes it easier for the blood to get up there and stay there long enough to form clouds.
Low/Non-oxygen
You want a very sterile atmosphere that won't interact with the blood or allow it to decay. Maybe something nitrogen-based? Not a vacuum though as too low-pressure and you get ebullism (boiling). You'd probably still need a little oxygen or a way to prevent it being lost from the blood.
Very cold
For the same reason you go with something cold to help the blood stay fresh and prevent drying. Not freezing though as that will crystalize it and damage the cells.
Low Radiation
Blood is fairly resistant to regular light but I doubt that holds up over long periods of time and for other types and intensities of radiation. You might need a low-light, low-radiation environment to sustain airborne blood over long periods of time and prevent cell mutations.
Other organics
You might need to add some organic elements to the air and blood pools that help keep the blood stable/fresh over longer periods. Not sure what those would be but possibly bacteria that mimic some processes that also happen inside bodies/organs. Maybe some airborne creatures or microbes that ingest stale blood and excrete healthy blood.
Living planet
You could run with the idea that the planet is not entirely mineral and go for something living/organic. That would make a lot of sense as both a source of the blood and a consumer. In this situation as long as there's some barrier between the surface of the world and space it could be sustainable. Keep in mind though the gravity of a living planet would definitely kill it so maybe just keep the organic component as a thin surface layer or make the planet very, very small.
There's probably other factors but essentially you're trying to mimic processes and environments inside a body and have it all outside so understanding how blood is sustained in a body is the key to sustaining it outside one.

The planet itself is a living being, so large it has an atmosphere and oxygenating plant life. It does not have lungs however, so it bleeds to breathe. It literally sprays geysers of its own blood into air where it exchanges oxygen and then it settles into huge oceans where the planet reinfuses itself with oxygenated blood.

Zombies!
Long ago, your planet was inhabited by short-lived, fearful mammals.  Their scientists invented a safety mechanism to stave off death, by wiring the mitochondria of their cells to a battery backup, and giving their neurally linked computers the autonomy to walk them back to the hospital when they were mentally incapacitated.  Needless to say, things did not go well: freedom fighters hacked the network, giving non-'enhanced' humans a chance to survive by activating the emergency trauma protocol en masse and reducing their augmented superiors to a form that closely resembles the walking dead.  Some of them may yet stalk the barrows and ruins, hunting for unwary protein to stoke the fuel cells in their bellies.
As powerful as the AI control of this distributed network may be, and as clever its enhancement of humans, the walking dead can't walk forever.  Pieces of their bodies are hacked off by uncooperative victims and other wild animals.  Floors and bridges fail and they are dashed to the rocks below.  Over time, the disconnected parts of their bodies - each with its own imperative to stay alive - work together to survive no matter what, until such time as someone with an admin password can designate a valid destination hospital for them to go to.
Just so, we see this network of human flesh, once a triumph of capitalism, has taken on a downright communistic bent.  Human digestive cells and brain organoids riddle all the fallow fields of this fallen world, sucking just as much life out of the grasses and trees as they can spare.  They package this material into the universal currency of circulatory transportation: the blood cell.  Red blood cells, with added glycogen and essential vitamins and minerals, ready to sustain each zombie according to its needs.  White blood cells, computer-enhanced so each is autonomously capable of designing T cell receptors and antibodies that can neutralize any pathogen or competitor they encounter.  Even platelets, now optimized to tie together the blood cells into any microscopic structure of use, such as to seal the surface of blood lakes from the natural evaporation of their precious water.  These blood cells fly aloft around the world, falling in mist and droplets wherever they are needed.
The blood cells have greater ability to control the materials science of their membranes than they once did in natural humans.  They can be as dry as smoke, as fine as dust, blown away in the slightest breeze; or they can feel wet and inviting as they probe natural prey for indicators that by their programmed rules may allow them to be targeted for colonization.  They can form tiny flying wings together, flagellae for propulsion, or grand cloud banks the size of a small nation.  They move as they see fit.  They rule the skies.  They watch.  They plan.  They think with a network that spans the globe.  They control more intact 'zombies' in secure hiding places than anyone could guess.  And they will not be deterred from their enduring survival objective.

Not possible science-based.
Blood ("real blood", biological, human blood) is not a homogeneous liquid of red color only. Also it is not just more viscous than water for example.
It contains blood cells (which account for the red color and also carry oxygen bound to them), certain molecules (like sugars, fats, hormones etc.) and even lifeforms (T-cells) in it (list is not exhaustive) - alongside the blood plasma (which is "amber" in color and more like water in nature).
Because the heavier elements will sink to the ground over time, the blood plasma separates and will end up swimming "on top". Also, if blood is exposed to (free) oxygen (from the atmosphere), it will change into congealed/clotted blood. Turning dark brown, solidifies and might begin to rot as well.
Have a look at the "amber" color here (it actually looks a lot like urine): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_plasma
This shows the separation phases (blood cells on the ground, plasma on top): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_fractionation
So, you need to clarify what you want to have by saying "real blood". If you mean real "real blood", see above. This planet would be an awful place to be at (for humans at least). Otherwise you probably just want a red colored substance which behaves like water and is just named "blood" - or some kind of alien, non-human blood.
Also, a "water cycle" would not be possible with "real blood", because the elements of the blood are not equally treatable like water. For example, blood cells would not be able to get into clouds and rain down again. They would decompose and then the main element, which provides the red color, would be missing.

Spores from algae
Just as on earth, algae are common. On this planet they fill the water and are airborn, filling the rain. All water as such looks red because it's filled with algae. While it's impossible for the rain to be that bloody because blood isn't airborn, the water itself takes on the consistency of blood when exposed to the sun with the algae having the exact consistency of blood and a similar taste and nature.

Clearly stated in the question: it also rains blood.

Every answer has noted that actual blood raining isn't science based, and their tag was science based.

Maybe your planets blood cycle isn't through evaporation, but animals living and dying.  The blood is kind of indestructible or atomic in nature or even living in its own right and when an animal dies it gives up its blood back to the ocean, seas and rivers, in the same way animals give up their flesh to the soil
